# I have encrypted data in the database how to decrypt it before displaying in the frontend in crocodic-studio / crudbooster?

Tags: laravel-5, encryption, crudbooster

I have the following form -

```
$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Client Name','name'=>'client_id','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|integer|min:0','width'=>'col-sm-10','datatable'=>'client,client_name','datatable_where'=>'status=1'];
$this->form[] = ['label'=>'Client Code','name'=>'user_id','type'=>'select','validation'=>'required|integer|min:0','width'=>'col-sm-10','datatable'=>'cms_users,name','datatable_where'=>'id_cms_privileges = 3 and blocked=0','parent_select'=>'client_id'];
```

cms_users,name is encrypted using the laravel encryption - `Crypt::encryptString($postdata['name'], env('ENC_KEY'));`

Now the problem is when I am clicking on the Client name dropdown I get the encrypted value in the Client Code dropdown.

I want to decrypt the value before displaying to the Client Code dropdown. How to solve this issue??

[image]